# Not showing data from django to highcharts

Tags: django, highcharts, django-views

I'm trying to retrieve a object from a queryset in django object and show it in my html graph by highcharts.

```
Models: 
class PbaSetOperator(models.Model):
    work_ymd = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    line_nm = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    prodc_qty = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    work_mh = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    in_house = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    reduction = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

views:

```
def setWorkerView(request):
    basic_st = 5.134
    set_operator = PbaSetOperator.objects.all()
    set_operator_today = set_operator.filter(work_ymd__range=(date,date1)).values('line_nm').order_by('line_nm').annotate(
                set_operator_today_value=((480 * (Sum('in_house') / Sum('work_mh'))) / ((1 - (Sum('reduction') /
                                                                                             (Sum('reduction') +
                                                                                              Sum('in_house')))) * basic_st)))
    
    context = {'set_operator_today':set_operator_today}
    
    return render(request, 'monitoring/setOperator.html', context)
```

html highcharts (pice of code):

```
{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Today',
    data: [
    {% for instance in set_operator_day %}
           {{ instance.set_operator_today_value|floatformat:0 }},
    {% endfor %}
            ], color: 'blue'
},
```

The column graph is not appearing in the graph by highcrats, but I can see properly if I show it inside a table:

```
<tr>
{% for instance in set_operator_today %}
            <td>{{ instance.set_operator_today_value|floatformat:0 }}</td>           
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: do you see any error message in the browser console? How does the rendered html/js code look like?

Comment: In my console is showing this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')

Comment: I have just plotted with the principal queryset and it work properly.

set_operator = PbaSetOperator.objects.all()


The problem looks like a type issue after the calculations in set_operator_today queryset

Comment: as you mention that the version with "td" works well, I suppose there is just a problem in the js for highcharts. Please post the complete error message - There should be more information like where in the code the error happens. This error does not necessarily have to do with the data definition but can be somewhere else related to highcharts. Please also post the code.

Comment: In this [article](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/create-a-dashboard-using-highcharts-and-django/) you will find how to pass the data may help solve your problem.